# Testcafe script failed with this error 'Call resulted in redirect and therefore should not cause other actions.:\n No stack trace available'

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I cannot put my code here due to company policies. But I'll post the entire error and the steps I followed here.

```html
   { type: 'uncaughtErrorOnPage',
  isTestCafeError: true,
  callsite:
   CallsiteRecord {
     filename:
      'path to file name',
     lineNum: 29,
     callsiteFrameIdx: 6,
     stackFrames:
      [ [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite] ],
     isV8Frames: true },
  errStack:
   'Call resulted in redirect and therefore should not cause other actions.:\n    No stack trace available',
  pageDestUrl: 'https://www.sample.com',
  isRejectedDriverTask: true }
```

I gave the url to launch in testcafe as shown here: `**fixt.page('https://www.launchtheurl.com');**`

But when it launches it'll redirect to another page with URL `https://www.sample.com` and there it'll enter login details and click on login button as well. And immediately the script will fail to throw the error mentioned above. I couldn't find any solution for this in any testcafe thread in DevExpress, so asking here.

If more information is required please let me know in comments so that I can provide whatever I can.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this information is not sufficient to find the cause of the issue.

I suggest you turn on the [`--skip-js-errors`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors) option.

If it does not help, you need to prepare a sample example to reproduce this issue. Feel free to open a new issue on the TestCafe repository using [the bug template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).

Comment: Found out the issue, it was the error that generated in console of browser that resulted in stopping the execution. Though, it won't create any problem while using the application manually. Is there a way to avoid failing the test scripts due to these issues? I tried ` --skip-js-errors` and `--skip-uncaught-errors`, but both times the execution stopped showing the same issue. And this is happening with only Chrome browser. In Firefox it's running without failing.

Comment: Likely TestCafe can't create a proper sandbox for scripts from your page. We can't properly research and fix such issue without a sample page.